# How to publish progress from work manager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using work manager to upload a video in my app. I am passing video file path to Work Manager and in work manager, I am making it chunks and upload to API. 1 video file can be many chunks and each chunk is uploaded to server sequentially (parallel upload not possible). So I want to call upload function on response of each chunk unless it is last chunk. For each chunk upload response, i need to update the progress in UI. Only if the chunk is last chunk then I want to return Result.Success(). But when I try to do this , I am getting error in code as below

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Single<ListenableWorker.Result?>
Found: Single<Any?>
```

PFB the code of my Work Manager

```
@HiltWorker
class UploadVideoWorkManager @AssistedInject constructor(
@Assisted val context: Context, @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
private val videoRepository: VideoRepository,
private val coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
private val analyticsManager: AnalyticsManager
) : RxWorker(context, params) {

private lateinit var videoData: VideoData
private val fileQueue: BlockingQueue<VideoData> = ArrayBlockingQueue(Constants.CHUNKS_LIMIT)

override fun createWork(): Single<Result?> {
    val vehicleId = inputData.keyValueMap[ParamKeys.VEHICLE_ID] as Int
    val path = inputData.keyValueMap[ParamKeys.PATH] as String
    val localId = inputData.keyValueMap[ParamKeys.LOCAL_ID] as String
    val videoSize = inputData.keyValueMap[ParamKeys.FILE_SIZE] as Long
    videoData =
        VideoData(itemId = vehicleId, filePath = path, localId = localId, fileSize = videoSize)
    convertFileToChunks()
    showNotification()
    return upload(fileQueue.take())
}

private fun convertFileToChunks() {
    val chunks = splitFile(File(videoData.filePath!!))
    if (chunks.isNotEmpty()) {
        for ((chunkNumber, chunk) in chunks.withIndex()) {
            val isLastChunk = chunkNumber == (chunks.size - 1)
            val videoChunk =
                videoData.copy(
                    chunkNumber = chunkNumber,
                    chunkFilePath = chunk.absolutePath,
                    chunksTotal = chunks.size,
                    lastChunk = isLastChunk
                )
            fileQueue.put(videoChunk)
        }
    }
}

private fun upload(chunk: VideoData): Single<Result?> {
    Logger.debug(msg = "----->>> Upload started " + chunk.chunkNumber)
    return videoRepository.uploadVideo(
        chunk.itemId,
        chunk.chunkFilePath!!,
        chunk.chunkNumber,
        chunk.chunksTotal,
        videoData.fileSize
    )
        .subscribeOnIoAndObserveOnMainThread()
        .map { result ->
            if (result.networkResult == NetworkResult.SUCCESS) {
                result.data?.let {
                    Logger.debug(msg = "----->>> Upload success " + videoData.fileSize + " chunk no: " + chunk.chunkNumber + " on server" + it.data?.onServer)
                    if (!chunk.lastChunk) {
                        upload(fileQueue.take())
                        setProgressAsync(workDataOf("progress" to 10))
                    }else {
                        val outputData =
                            workDataOf(
                                ParamKeys.VEHICLE_ID to chunk.itemId,
                                ParamKeys.LOCAL_ID to chunk.localId,
                                ParamKeys.VIDEO_ID to it.data?.id,
                                ParamKeys.PATH to it.data?.url
                            )
                        Result.success(outputData)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Logger.debug(msg = "----->>> Upload error ")
                Result.failure(
                    workDataOf(
                        ParamKeys.VEHICLE_ID to chunk.itemId,
                        ParamKeys.LOCAL_ID to chunk.localId
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        .onErrorReturn { error ->
            Logger.debug(msg = "----->>> Upload exception  ")
            error.printStackTrace()
            Result.failure(
                workDataOf(
                    ParamKeys.VEHICLE_ID to chunk.itemId,
                    ParamKeys.LOCAL_ID to chunk.localId
                )
            )
        }
}

private fun showNotification() {
    setForeground(
        createNotification(
            context,
            context.getString(R.string.video_notification_content)
        )
    )
}
}
```